# How do I display text above after submitting it into a textbox HTML

Tags: html, form-submit

I'm trying to create an area in which you can enter text into a text box and display the written text onto a box above in HTML. I'm very new to HTML so any help will be greatly appreciated. I drew a beautiful picture of what I'm trying to make. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to deal with this situation is use Javascript or jQuery which is javascript's library itself. Let me show you how you should do it in jQuery

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#form-to-be-submitted").click(function(){
         $(".whatever-styling-you-want").html($("#textBox").val());
        });
    });
 
</script>

<div class="whatever-styling-you-want">

</div>
<!-- Your text box and submit button -->
<div>
      <input type="text" id="textBox" placeholder="Please input your text here..."/>
      <input id="form-to-be-submitted" value="submit" type="button"/>
</div>
```

Javascript's way is also the same. No need to use the click function but use javascript's on function with the 'click' event.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<p id="x"></p><br>
<input id="value"><input type="button" value="submit" onClick="getV()">
<script>
function getV(){document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = document.getElementById("value").value;}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You wanted to know why your answers are down voted, then please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions.

Comment: I agree you need to read the link I posted in the comment, it explains very clearly why this is a low quality answer.

Comment: a BLOB of code with no explanation of why it there is not a good answer, never has been, never will be.